# Unsure what to do with this Compile error

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile some C source code (https://github.com/smcameron/space-nerds-in-space)
PC is running Ubuntu 18.04

I run into the following error when I run the 'make' command

```
COMPILE mathutils.c
cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wstringop-truncation'; did you mean '-Wline-truncation'?
Makefile:967: recipe for target 'object_files/mathutils.o' failed
make: *** [object_files/mathutils.o] Error 1
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Your compiler does not support `-Wstringop-truncation` so search for it in the makefile(s) and remove it. Btw, are you on a Linux machine? The game requires Linux.

Comment: run cc --version. If it is < 9 then your compiler is too old and does not support it.

Comment: Yes its Linux - Ubuntu 18

Comment: The compiler option is only useful for the developers of the project to get some warnings about potential problems in the code, so as a consumer who is only trying to build the project, it should be safe to remove the option. I see you have reported it as an issue, so perhaps the developers will add some make-time compiler checks to see if the option is supported. However Ubuntu 18.04 has reached the end of its standard LTS support period (it is now in its paid-for ESM period), so perhaps it is time for you to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, thats useful to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @gulpr

My version of gcc was 7.5
Once updated to version 10, problem solved

Comment: Since this solves the problem then how about you accept this answer?

Comment: @theroyn: It is a self-answer, and there are limits (of the order of a couple of days) on how quickly such answers can be accepted.

Comment: Note that even if GCC 10 is the latest version available on your (somewhat ancient) version of Ubuntu, it is not the latest version of GCC; that would be GCC 13.2.